# Cypress element is not visible because it has an effective width and height of 0 x 0 pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, cypress

I am getting below error when performing action on a element in a iframe:

"Timed out retrying after 60000ms: expected '

' to be 'visible' This element

is not visible because it has an effective width and height of: 0 x 0 pixels."

[image]

Here is my code for the element:

```
cy.get('iframeselector',{timeout: 150000})
    .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')
    .then(cy.wrap).find('p').should('be.visible').clear().type('abc')
```

I have tried using {force:true} and even changing the width by invoke method. but nothing works for me so far. Any help will be appreciated.

Below is the snap of html:
[image]

Comment: I even went through https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2000 and https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/695 but nothing worked for me so far

Comment: Can you create small reproducible example repo and share it with us?

Comment: "and even changing the width by invoke method" You'd have to change both the width and the height.

Comment: @Manuel Abascal have added the html snap in the question

Comment: @Ouroborus the invoke method didn't change the width. The width before and after calling the invoke function remained same.

Comment: What if you skip check that its visible and `clear({force: true})` ?

Comment: I get the 0x0 pixel error, so i added the isvisible condition. also force:true was not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. There are 3 other iframes in the page and each iframe is inside a container. I intended to perform action on element insode the 2nd iframe and by default my code was trying to work on element in 1st iframe.

Cyress did not give the error about multiple iframes being found found. So it threw me off with the 0x0 pixel error. Following worked for me:

```
  cy.get('parentContainer').within(()=>{
        cy.get('iframeselector',{timeout: 150000})
        .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')
        .then(cy.wrap).find('p').should('be.visible').clear().type('abc')
})
```